# Touch event can't be consumed in mono

Tags: c#, java, android, event-handling, mono

I've recently moved from Java to C# and Mono for Android development.  I have a ListView which I want to optionally return true or false from but in Mono there doesn't seem to be an option to do so.  Here are some code snippets:

Java (that I'm trying to reproduce in Mono)

```
ListView listview;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        adapter.add(Integer.toString(i));

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    listview.setOnTouchListener(listenerOnTouch);
}

private OnTouchListener listenerOnTouch = new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        return false; // <---- This line doesn't exist in Mono
    }
};
```

Mono equivalent:

```
    ListView listview;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        listview = FindViewById(Resource.Id.listView1) as ListView;
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1);

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            adapter.Add (i.ToString());

        listview.Adapter = adapter;
        listview.Touch += ListenerOnTouch;
    }

    private void ListenerOnTouch(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        // Delegate return type is void, so I can't return true/false
    }
```

Fundamentally, what I'm trying to do in this instance is make is so that if I drag the list view up or down it scrolls as normal, but if I drag it left or right it does something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, May be e.Handled needs to set true/false as of your requirement.

[Handling Touch Event](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=T%3aAndroid.Views.View.TouchEventArgs)